# Why does my striped background scale with such a bad quality?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that includes a striped background image. Click to enlarge – this is the original image I'm using. There's also a version with a logo for another activity.

[image]

It looks fine as is. I set it as a background in the activity through XML, something like this.

I need the hack as an ImageView to be able to properly `centerCrop` a logo in the background, but this is irrelevant to the issue, as it persists when setting the `background` for the `RelativeLayout` and removing the `ImageView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_striped" />
```

Note that since there has to be a logo inside the image, I can't stretch it artificially or have it repeat.

---

In the layout preview screen, it looks like this:

[image]

In the emulator, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it looks quite bad, compared to how I'd expect it:

[image]

Naturally, I've created versions of the striped background for all display resolutions (from `ldpi` to `xhdpi`), but they always seem to be scaled in a pretty bad way.

Is there any way to get the background scaled in a higher quality? Just using the `xhdpi` version won't result in better quality—it will just make the scale result worse and more washed out.

Comment: Do you want it to stretch or to repeat?

Comment: Why you cant set a nine-patch image instead ?

Comment: @Barend It should be stretched, keeping the aspect ratio. I can't repeat it, as the final version will carry a logo inside. And of course, I can't stretch the logo.

Comment: @RajeshCP Do you mean expanding the stretch with the 9-patch? I'm not sure if that'd easily work if the logo has to be in the background—that's the reason I'm using one image in the first place and no repetition.

Comment: It is basically will be a png Image what you are using now, so if you set it as a background for a view obviously it will stretch. Why you cant separate the logo from the background ant set it as a separate view ?

Comment: @RajeshCP Hm. I've never thought about separate logo placement. That might be possible indeed, but it might be complicated to have it float where I want it with all the other elements.

Comment: You can create a custom view and add the logo as child to the custom view and use that particular view any where you want :)

Answer (score 1):

For scalable drawables it is better to use a 9-patch. You can create one with your small striped background image using the android 9-patch tool:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `repeat`. I tested it and it seems to look fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:src="@drawable/background_striped"
 android:tileMode="repeat" />
```